# after updating shiny r package an "invalid JSON input" error

Tags: r, shiny

I updated my shiny r package and now I got this error:

```
.clientdatError in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
  invalid JSON input
```

Does anyone know what's happening here or where to look for the cause of the problem?

many thanks in advance!

edit. It has something to do with the tags function. When I remove e.g. tags$textarea(id="text", rows=5, cols=8, "this is a text area") the error doesn't appear anymore.